# Swift : click on a UIButton with code

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to simulate a UIButton click only with code, is this possible ?

For example I would like to do :

```
if (mytest == true)
{
    myButton.click()
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myButton.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you are asking would be having a function which would be targeted by that button. e.g.

```
@IBAction func clickButton(sender: UIButton){
//your Functionality
}
```

you may call something like

```
self.clickButton(nil);//or even you  may pass your button
```